# Directory hierarchy of locally installed packages

Tags: linux

I am a user in a Linux server and I do not have root permissions. Thus, I install my own packages locally in my home directory (usually using `make --prefix`).
What is the standard (whatever standard means) directory hierarchy to place installed packages locally in the home directory?

Comment: There's none, at least non i've heard of. There is [FHS](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) standard for all files in system, but none for "user locally installed packages".

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I mean it does not need to be a standard way. A recommended or a popular way of organizing packages in the home directory is what I need.